# How to access Angular app in docker container via nginx reverse proxy

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to use docker to containerize services, including an Angular app. Each of the services uses `/service-name` as the end of the url.

If I make a toy flask service, I can access it just fine at `locahost:3333/toy-flask-service`, but when trying to do the same with Angular (e.g. `locahost:3333/angular-service`) then I get errors. Admittedly the flask service is a simple example using the built in dev server, but the angular service is using nginx within the same container.

Say I have the following containers the hold the following:

- reverse-proxy (nginx accessible via port 3333)
- main_client (vue.js using development service that occupies the root path)
- service_1 (flask app using a development server)
- angular-service (angular app using nginx)

If I run the container with the angular app, I can access it via `localhost:4200` just fine. It loads correctly.

If I try and access it via localhost:3333/angular-service, then I get javascript console errors like the following...

```
Loading module from “http://localhost:3333/runtime-es2017.b7ccab836de1e8b6cb8e.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).
```

If I go to `http://localhost:3333/angular-service/runtime-es2017.b7ccab836de1e8b6cb8e.js` then the browser shows the content of the .js file, so the console errors seem to imply it's trying to look for it without taking the preceding `angular-service/` path into account.

I hope I'm correct in assuming that the angular container should be able to be configured as if it's completely independent of the reverse proxy, and it's the nginx.config file for the reverse proxy that is configured incorrectly. It doesn't seem right that I'd have to use `--base-href` and `--deploy-url` when building the angular app to account for the `/angular-service` path

Here's the DockerFile I use for creating the angular + nginx image.

```
#stage 1
FROM node:14.21-slim as node
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run ng -- build --prod

#stage 2
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=node /app/dist/my-app /usr/share/nginx/html
```

The angular container's ngix.config is the default.

The upstream reverse-proxy looks like

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  server {
    listen 3333;
    server_name localhost 127.0.0.1;

    location / {
        proxy_pass          http://main-client-app:80;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }

    location /toy-flask-service {
        proxy_pass          http://toy-flask-service:5001/;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }

    location /angular-service {
        proxy_pass          http://angular-service:80/;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;  
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;  
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';  
        proxy_set_header Host $host;  
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
  }
}
```

Note that if I change the location of the angular service to be at the root position i.e. `location /` (and remove the `main-client`), then the angular app loads correctly. It just doesn't seem to like the non-root path.

I've read somewhere that adding `include /etc/nginx/mime.types;` to the `http` block helps, but it didn't in my case.

I've also experimented with `rewrite /?angular-service/(.*)$ /$1 break;` (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52291042/angular-app-running-on-nginx-and-behind-an-additional-nginx-reverse-proxy)), and tried `try_files` (from [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/1089374/nginx-serving-multiple-angular-applications-static-files-missing-error))

```
location ~ ^/angular-service/.*\.(html|js|css|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|png|gif|ico|jpg|jpeg)$ {    
    try_files $request_uri $request_uri/ =404;  
}
```

What am I missing in the nginx.conf of the reverse proxy to solve the path issues for Angular?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nginx was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”). Angular 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60403250/nginx-was-blocked-because-of-a-disallowed-mime-type-text-html-angular-8)

Comment: I had tried using the --base-href and --deploy-url at one point, but got issues with translations not loading. Images worked though. I could have another attempt, but it doesn't seem right to me that the DockerFile for the Angular+nginx container has to be changed just because of the way the revsere proxy nginx is set up. If the reverse-proxy changes the path from say, /angular-service to /api, then the the angular+nginx container also needs updating. It doesn't seem right.

Comment: @E.Maggini Turns out the translations issue was an Angular code issue where I had /assets/i18n/${lang}.json instead of assets/i18n/${lang}.json, which was messing with the paths. For my immediate concerns, yes, you are correct in that --base-href /angular-service was required to at least give me something that works, but the problem is by doing so, the Angular+nginx container as an independent container "breaks" because localhost:4200 is no longer accessible. I was hoping for an nginx technique to solve this in the reverse-proxy, e.g. prepend angular-service/ to asset folder lookups.