# Mime type disallowed and failure loading polyfills, main and runtime.js files

Tags: javascript, angular, nginx, deployment, mime-types

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3G3K.png)

I deployed an internal angular application on the server using nginx configuration. Polyfills.js, main.js, runtime.js are generated due to angular in the dist folder. There files refused to be loaded on the browser due to disallowed MIME Types.

When I launch the application locally on my desktop, everything works find and I could see the application on localhost:80.

I don't understand how to solve those disallowed MIME Types Error for the application to appear on the browser.

Since our application should run on a domain [www.example.com/user](http://www.example.com/user), how should I configure my nginx?

Comment: You should use text for your error and not an image description. If you want to know why, you can consult this [post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60403250/nginx-was-blocked-because-of-a-disallowed-mime-type-text-html-angular-8) may help you resolve your error.